# Some nosql cosmosdb advice required

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am looking for some advice in designing an application using NoSQL CosmosDB or relevant technology.

The data structure looks like the following currently:

```
{
     "accounts": [{
             "name": "name1",
             "type": "type1"
         },
         {
             "name": "name2",
             "type": "type2"
         }
     ],
     "categories": [{
             "master": "mastername",
             "child": [
                 "child1name",
                 "child2name"
             ]
         },
         {
             "master": "mastername2",
             "child": [
                 "child3name",
                 "child4name"
             ]
         }
     ],
     "charts": {

     },
     "grouping": [{
         "2018": [{
             "06": {
                 "property1": "value1",
                 "property2":"value2"
             },
             "07": {
                 "property1": "value2",
                 "property2":"value2",
                 "property3":"value3"
             }
         }]
     }],
     "ItemsList": [{
             "id": "2018051720",
             "dateMonth": "201807",
             "property1": "value2",
             "date": "17/07/2018",
             "Description": "description2"
         },
         {
             "id": "2018051720",
             "datemonth": "201807",
             "property1": "value1",
             "date": "17/07/2018",
             "Description": "description"
         }
     ],
     "id": "7b786960c93cc9a8"
 }
```

Currently I have decided to have the one collection, because of budget concerns and inside that, will have a multiple of the data structure you see above, so like a list of it.

My question is, is this a good design, the reason for asking is that the following elements can grow quite substantially over time.

ItemList and Grouping.

Itemlist will grow every month by users adding to it, and Grouping will be for every year and month, once a month, but updated as ItemList items are added. Categories and accounts could also change but irregularly.

If I have this in one collection, I was thinking maybe I somehow, have the following structure:

```
// Main Object
 {
     "accounts": [{
             "name": "name1",
             "type": "type1"
         },
         {
             "name": "name2",
             "type": "type2"
         }
     ],
     "categories": [{
             "master": "mastername",
             "child": [
                 "child1name",
                 "child2name"
             ]
         },
         {
             "master": "mastername2",
             "child": [
                 "child3name",
                 "child4name"
             ]
         }
     ],
     "charts": {

     },
     "id": "7b786960c93cc9a8"
 }

 // Groupings list
 {
     "grouping": [{
             "userid": "7b786960c93cc9a8",
             "grouping": {
                 "2018": [{
                     "06": {
                         "property1": "value1",
                         "property2": "value2"
                     },
                     "07": {
                         "property1": "value2",
                         "property2": "value2",
                         "property3": "value3"
                     }
                 }]
             }
         },
         {
             "userid": "sfkjehffkjwhf34343",
             "grouping": {
                 "2018": [{
                     "04": {
                         "property1": "value1",
                         "property2": "value2"
                     },
                     "05": {
                         "property1": "value2",
                         "property2": "value2",
                         "property3": "value3"
                     },
                     "06": {
                         "property1": "value2",
                         "property2": "value2",
                         "property3": "value3"
                     }
                 }]
             }
         }
     ]
 }

 // Item List List
 {
     "ItemLists": [{
             "userid": "7b786960c93cc9a8",
             "itemlist": [{
                     "id": "2018051720",
                     "dateMonth": "201807",
                     "property1": "value2",
                     "date": "17/07/2018",
                     "Description": "description2"
                 },
                 {
                     "id": "2018051720",
                     "datemonth": "201807",
                     "property1": "value1",
                     "date": "17/07/2018",
                     "Description": "description"
                 }
             ]
         },
         {
             "userid": "sfkjehffkjwhf34343",
             "itemlist": [{
                     "id": "2018051720",
                     "dateMonth": "201807",
                     "property1": "value2",
                     "date": "17/07/2018",
                     "Description": "description2"
                 },
                 {
                     "id": "2018051720",
                     "datemonth": "201807",
                     "property1": "value1",
                     "date": "17/07/2018",
                     "Description": "description"
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]
 }
```

As you can see, I will basically have the main object list with it growing like normal, and then the other json objects for itemlist and grouping where it can grow indepentdantly from the main object, but it would require Two Reads then or even three RU's for the website. Working on only having 400 RU's a month basically, its not a lot of user base and objects?

What is the best way to do this while thinking about money, because if money was no problem, I would have prob gone with a collection for each, where the main object just references the other collection by Id or something.

Hope it makes a bit of sense, in my head it does :)

Comment: Unfortunately such a question is off-topic, as it's very broad, and the answer is going to depend highly on your particular app, query needs, performance, etc. The only thing to call out is that documents have a maximum size, and your document model has several *unbounded* arrays (meaning they can grow indefinitely). This pretty much points to you reaching maximum document size eventually (and at that point, your app will break until you refactor your schema).

Comment: Also note that RU is a measure of available resources *per second*, not per month. 400RU means you have 400 RU per second. You'll need to benchmark your operations to see how many RU each one costs, and what RU level you might need for your given app. Different queries have different costs. And writes have varying RU based on object size, # of properties indexed, etc.

Comment: Finally, note that, to use 400 RU, that means you're using a single-partition 10GB collection. It can never grow beyond 10GB. To avoid this, you would need to use partitioned collections (with a starting cost of 1000RU).

Answer (score -1):

Imho you're making the age-old mistake of worrying about optimization before a problem arises. Also your sentence "Working on only having 400 RU's a month" somehow makes me feel like you should read up more on the topic of RU's

[Check here for Information about RU's and tools to estimate your throughput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units)

400 RU's which cap's your collections "throughput" might slow down your end-user's experience (there might be other bottle necks - usually their on-premise internet connection)

You can always watch the usage of your collections in the Azure Portal and upscale within minutes - so you cannot go wrong by starting with 400RUs

**Every request not made is the biggest possible boost to performance**

Request in CosmosDB are already bloated with headers for security - you will not have notable performance boosts for shaving a few bytes off your objects here and there, but local caching (be it on your webserver or on the user's machine) will, and it's very easy to do if you simply store the whole Json Objects as key-value pairs (basically what CosmosDB does).

What **would be wrong** in my opinion is considering multiple collections. I think you have misunderstood the concept there a little. One collection per customer/project is usually the way to go, so don't worry. Everything is indexed and uniquely ID'ed internally so separating things is no problem. One collection per "object type" makes the advantage of any NoSQL Database moot.

If you worry about your "internal lists" getting too long, just save them separately and only save their id in the original object. Then you load them on-demand in your application. Generally speaking more small objects are better than few large objects - if you are able to load them cleverly in your application.

So instead of this:

```
{
 "userid": "sfkjehffkjwhf34343",
 "grouping": {
     "2018": [{
         "04": {
             "property1": "value1",
             "property2": "value2"
         },
         "05": {
             "property1": "value2",
             "property2": "value2",
             "property3": "value3"
         },
         "06": {
             "property1": "value2",
             "property2": "value2",
             "property3": "value3"
         }
     }]
 }
}
```

you could do this instead

```
{
    "userid": "sfkjehffkjwhf34343",
    "grouping": {
     "2018": ["x1","x2","x3"]
    }
}

{
    "groupingid": "x1",
    "month":"04",
    "values": {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": "value2"
    }
}

{
    "groupingid": "x2",
    "month":"05",
    "values": {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property3": "value3",
        "property2": "value2"
    }
}

{
    "groupingid": "x3",
    "month":"06",
    "values": {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": "value2"
    }
}
```

Load them only if needed, cache them according to their internal id (which changes on every update if you leave it out) and you won't believe how performant this can be.

You should read up on **stored procedures** also,  they are a really powerful and in some cases a true gold mine for performance improvements.

There is a lot of good Information from Microsoft out there, though admittedly it's not easy to find sometimes.

CosmosDB is frankly an incredible powerful tool if used correctly, but I encourage you to read up on it a little more you you can use it effectively, performance- and cost-wise.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer has incorrect information. There is no such equivalence of 400RU=400kb/sec. RU is related to query complexity, index creation, etc. Every operation has an associated RU cost, which is predictable & consistent (but nothing to do with bytes/sec). You've also immediately asserted that multiple collections are wrong. Again, there's no such rule. This is especially important when dealing with partitioned collections: different data types might need to be partitioned differently for optimum RU cost.

Comment: Also, stored procedures, while very valuable, are not a silver bullet that makes somebody awesome. For example, when using partitioned collections, they are scoped to a single partition, which might not give the desired results.

Comment: Last comment: The question itself is off-topic (it's *very* broad). There's simply no right answer to this. Just opinions and discussion. Best not to try answering such a question.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMakogon, sorry you feel the question is inadequate of answering. I don't know any other way to state my question other than my example. I am looking for some best practices with cosmosdb where there aren't really a lot of info, except for referencing and embedding into objects etc. I was looking for some people with real world experience to perhaps just guide me in the right directions, and hopefully that will still happen. Mightylc already has provided me with some info on rather referencing across objects in one collection, which is good advice.

Comment: @Martin - the issue is that this question is very broad. And providing general guidance doesn't fit here, because there are many ways to model data. There are also several tutorials and documents written by the Cosmos DB team that talk specifically about data modeling, which is probably the best place to start.

Comment: Reading this, "When you start modeling data in a document store, such as Azure Cosmos DB, try to treatyour entities as selfcontained
documents represented in JSON.", I need to keep each entity as self contained referencing other entities rather than embedding them. Making smaller calls to cosmos sql api to retrieve those entities like ItemList when I need it, and keeping the original main object smaller with these reference id's in it. And like you mentioned @DavidMakogon RU is based on CPU, memory and IOP, so bigger entity more RU. But then wonder what benefit nosql is giving me more  then?

Comment: thank you @DavidMakogon for your comments. I know that my equivalence is "rough" but as I stated the phrase akin to "I have only so much RU a month" felt like it was even more off -  I tried to provide a link with the best information about RU I could, though :(. The broad question made me view the OP as someone who is just getting started and needs to read up more on AzureDB. IMO you should not start developing any client applications for CosmosDB without knowing about all it has to offer server-sided - and there is not much Information out there and it's not easy to find.

Comment: @Martin you should use NoSQL if you have documents (database objects) with non-static structure. If you cannot see the advantage - maybe cosmosdb is the wrong choice altogether. That's what I was trying to do with my answer - have you read up on it a little more :)

Comment: @Martin If you want to contact me to tell me a little more about your project you can find my E-Mail in my profile. I have some real-life experience with cosmosdb - even though my impromptu definition of RU might not be spot-on ;)

Comment: I'm sorry @DavidMakogon, but the Downvote is starting to bother me. Here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#estimating-throughput-needs is a "rough" calculation recommendation for your throughput, linking RU's **directly** to Item-Size in kb. How is it that - as you say - RU have "nothing to do with bytes/sec". If that is so, this information is frankly, quite worthless.

Comment: @themightylc You are conflating things. Bytes/second is *throughput*. And that is not the same as item size. Also, you'll find that write-cost is impacted by the # of properties indexed. And point-reads (not queries) cost significantly less than queries. And this all circles back to why I said this was off-topic. This is a very big topic. There is lots of documentation explaining RUs, reads vs queries, indexing, partitioning, etc. And data modeling is quite varying in nature, depending on the app. Anyway... I won't comment anymore here. This has devolved into a discussion in comments.

Comment: I am conflating - imo the same as the article does to give users a way to roughly estimate **throughput** based on their objects - which of course **also** depends on the objects raw bytesize. It's the point of the whole throughput-calculator. You even said yourself "note that RU is a measure of available resources per **second**, not per **month.**" which is exactly the point I was trying to make. Did you downvote because of the inexact equivalency - or because I was trying to answer such a broad question at all? I was trying to give helpful information to the op. Where should he ask instead?